# How do I remove Keybase from my Finder Favorites?

Tags: macos, finder

[Keybase](https://keybase.io) adds a folder to my Finder favorites that I cannot remove. I've checked the Keybase issues database and this appears to be a [known but still not addressed issue](https://github.com/keybase/client/issues/7579), so I think I need to (1) stop using Keybase and (2) fix this in the Finder.

How do I do (2): how do I force the removal of an item from my Finder Favorites that I cannot remove in the normal way (using the items menu or dragging out of the sidebar)?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82703/discussion-on-question-by-orome-how-do-i-remove-keybase-from-my-finder-favorites).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following worked for me in **macOS High Sierra**.

To remove **Keybase** from under **Favorites** on **Finder's Sidebar**, I did the following:

1. Open: **Keybase**
2. Click: **Settings**
3. Click: **FILES**
4. Uncheck: **[] Enable Keybase in Finder**

[image]

5. Click the **Remove & Restart** button on the ensuing dialog box.

[image]

6. Drag **Keybase** from under **Favorites** on **Finder's Sidebar** until the **(x)** appears and then let go.

Even after rebooting my Mac, **Keybase** did not reappear under **Favorites** on **Finder's Sidebar**. All is as it should be and I can continue to use the other features of **Keybase**.

If you no longer want to use **Keybase** and completely remove the App and support files, then do the following:

1. Close the **Keybase** app and it's **Menu Extras** icon.

[image]

Then using **[AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/)**:

1. Open: **AppCleaner**
2. Drag and drop the **Keybase** app onto **AppCleaner**.
3. Click the **Remove** button.

[image]

---

<sub>Note: I am not affiliated with the developer of AppCleaner, just a satisfied user.</sub>

Comment: Those are the mentions steps that won’t work for me.

Comment: @orome, You never stated in your OP that you went in to the Keybase app and changed the settings!